# Does the MySQLdb module in python returns utf8 encoding or unicode in this case?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, mysql-python

Using MySQLdb I connect to a database where everything is stored in the utf8 encoding.

If I do

```
cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
```

and fetch some data from the database by another statement. Does that mean, that the strings in

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ...")
cursor.fetchall()
```

will be in unicode? Or do I have to turn them first by

```
mystr.decode("utf8")
```

to unicode?

Comment: For instance this string `repr("Naïve")` results in `Na\xc3\xafve`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Depends. Did you get that from the database?

Comment: Yes, the string `"Naïve"` is from the database. I grabbed it like I explained in my question above...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

> connect(parameters...)
>     ...
>
> > `use_unicode`
> >
> > > If True, CHAR and VARCHAR and TEXT columns are returned as Unicode strings, using the configured character set. It is best to set the default encoding in the server configuration, or client configuration (read with read_default_file). If you change the character set after connecting (MySQL-4.1 and later), you'll need to put the correct character set name in connection.charset.
> > >
> > > If False, text-like columns are returned as normal strings, but you can always write Unicode strings.
> > >
> > > This must be a keyword parameter.

Comment: I thought `cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8")` would make certain all string transfers between the database and the script will be in `utf8`. Does this mean if I do `cursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8")` and I have set the keyword parameter `use_unicode` my strings will be grabbed as `utf8` and will be returned as `unicode`?

Comment: You probably want the `charset` argument as well.